# PYTHON: how to avoid cyclic dependancy and combine local + global variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables

I need to feed *local variable* from one `python` file to another, combine the variables there and Then get the other variables back into first file.

I looked at SO discussions for `cyclic dependency` and `combining local and global variables`, but it does not seem to solve my problem.

Here is skeleton example of what I am trying to accomplish.
Couple of `python` scripts generates reports.

**#report1.py**

```
report_name = "daily_report1"
```

**#report2.py**

```
report_name = "daily_report2"
```

`report_name` is the variable for report name and needs to be sourced in `mysettings.py` that holds most of the environment variables and constants.

**#mysettings.py**

```
save_location=  os.getcwd()+ "\\" + report_name + "\\"
report_file = report_name + "_" +  \ 
str(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m_%d_%Y')) + ".xlsx"
```

The code then queries a server and gets a `csv` file and converts to `xlsx` and modifies as per needs.

Back in repor?.py

**#report1.py**

```
import mysettings.py

report_name = "daily_report1"

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(report_file)

#Lots of other code

wb.save(save_location + report_file)
```

**#report2.py**

```
import mysettings.py

report_name = "daily_report2"

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(report_file)

#Lots of other code

wb.save(save_location + report_file)
```

Challenge is, How do I feed in `report_name` to `mysettings.py` and then get the combined variable back in report1.py and report2.py

Once its working, there will be other reports added, hence I wanted to get variables/settings streamlined.

I also wanted to declare as less variables as possible in all the `reports?.py` and instead manage them globally in `mysettings.py`

Any thoughts input is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried running any of your hypothetical scripts? `import mysettings.py` is invalid and `report_name` is not defined in the global scope of `mysettings` module.  None of your example files make any sense!

Comment: Multiple modules do not share global namespaces, use a function to define `report_file` based on some `report_name` and then use it with `mysettings.generate_report_file(report_name)` in the other modules.

Comment: @Tadhg, I cant share actual file/code as its related to work. It working fine except I have all the variables listed in `report1.py` , `report2.py` instead of `mysettings.py`. I cant figure out how to source `report_name` in `mysettings.py`. also I may have more reports and I would need to update changes everywhere, which is what I am trying to avoid. thanks for your reply.

Comment: so you _want_ to basically [`exec`ute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) the code from `mysettings.py` in the scope of the reports?

Comment: Code will be executed in the `report.py` , `report2.py` since each report formats the data differently. I need to have all the needed variable in `mysettings.py` except which are report specific. Unfortunately, since the report name is prefix for `modified reports` and `report_folder`, I am having issues combining it with global names in another file (mysettings.py). Within same files `report`.py` is no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *define* a function in mysettings.py and *execute* it in other files:

#mysettings.py

```
def getsettings(report_name):
    save_location=  os.getcwd()+ "\\" + report_name + "\\"
    report_file = report_name + "_" +  \ 
    str(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m_%d_%Y')) + ".xlsx"
    return save_location, report_file
```

#report1.py

```
import mysettings.py

report_name = "daily_report1"
save_location, report_file = mysettings.getsettings(report_name)
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(report_file)

#Lots of other code
wb.save(save_location + report_file)
```

That way you do not need to use global variables across different scripts

Answer (score 0):

Ok the most strait forward way would be to execute the code in `mysettings.py` inside the report modules:

```
report_name = "blah"

with open("mysettings.py","r") as common_code:
    exec(f.read(), globals()) #the globals() is actually implied if there is no second argument

print(report_file)
```

However passing several variables between modules is usually handled by an `environment` dictionary, so you could have your `mysettings.py` have a function like this:

```
def generate_report_file(environ):
    report_name = environ["report_name"]
    environ["save_location"] =  os.getcwd()+ "\\" + report_name + "\\"
    environ["report_file"] = report_name + "_" +  \ 
             str(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m_%d_%Y')) + ".xlsx"
```

Then in the report files you can handle the environ dict manually:

```
environ = {}
environ["report_name"] = "blah"

mysettings.generate_report_file(environ)

print(environ["report_file"])
```

Or take advantage of the fact that the global namespace is kept track of with a dictionary:

```
report_name = "blah"

mysettings.generate_report_file(globals())

print(report_file)
```